# defaultValue в rc-Slider не отображется правильно

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, react-hook

Использую в проекте rs-Slider.
с родительского компонента через props передаю minPrice/maxPrice
далее записываю их в конфигурацию слайдера, но по дефолту эти значения почему то равняются единице.
Возможно я что то не учел в параметрах слайдера?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При загрузке страницы вот такой результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тестовая скрипка для понимания что происходит
https://codesandbox.io/s/rs-slider-46s3n?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

как оказалось помимо defaultValue необходимо указать в настройках слайдера
value: [value.min, value.max],
defaultValue: [value.min, value.max],